# An issue with reading DB when program runs at startup in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm new here and to vb.net and I'm stuck on something that I feel SHOULD be simple to resolve.  I setup my program to let the user decide if he or she wants to have the program run at windows start.  It actually works fine as it is assigning the registry value to CurrentUser instead of Local Machine because of admin rights needing to be bypassed.  However, when I restart my computer the program comes up like normal, but it will not read my access db that is located in the same folder as the program; it tries to read the DB from Windows\System32.

Is there a way to force it to read from the executablepath instead of System32?

**Here is my simple code:**

```
  Private Sub startup()

        If cbStartup.Checked = True Then

            My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("Windows").OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion").OpenSubKey("Run", True).SetValue("CC_List", System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath)

        ElseIf cbStartup.Checked = False Then

            My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Microsoft").OpenSubKey("Windows").OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion").OpenSubKey("Run", True).DeleteValue("CC_List", False)

        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Does "run at windows start" mean "before anyone logs in" ?  When you set the value, it gets set in a space that belongs to the logged in user.  But if you're trying to make it run when no-one is logged in, I'm not sure that currentuser has a value at all - I'm pretty sure it's not going to be the same as the last logged in user.  You might have more luck reviewing / posting the code that opens the database - see if you can get System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath in there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, the "System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath" is in the first part of the "IF" statement at the very end (was that what you meant?). :) And it has this error both with and without logging into a user account. I've tried it already in both scenarios. The program starts up fine. The scenario is that it has already been set by the user to automatically start up when windows loads. The CurrentUser does have a value set otherwise the program wouldn't load automatically at all, correct? I've also tested that the value was there when I added it.

Comment: isn't that enough with Application.StartupPath ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when the O/S starts your program the **Current Directory** is `%windir%\System32`.

You need to either adjust all your existing paths to be explicitly relative to `Application.ExecutablePath`, or put

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath
```

at the start of your program (which is the modern version of `ChDir ...`).

Comment: That done it.  Thanks Mark. :)
And thanks to the others for helping.

For the record I used:

My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath

Comment: @JaredD. .. you have to accept this as the answer .. make green check below downvote sign ..

Comment: My bad, was in a rush.  Done.